# Does MS SQL Server consolidate repeated aggregates within a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I'm working on performance tuning some aggregate-heavy queries, and I'm wondering whether repeating the same aggregate function over and over has a significant performance penalty.

I'm assuming MS SQL Server is intelligent enough to calculate each repeated aggregate only once, and then reuse the resultant value each time that exact aggregate is encountered within the same query - Is my assumption correct here?

The alternative to this is, we can add a bunch more joins to this view (joining the same tables over and over again), with varying `join on` clauses, to group rows together in a bunch of different ways to produce the various totals without reusing any aggregate functions more than once - but looking at the execution plans we can see that adding more joins definitely *does* make the query take longer, and we technically already have all the information we need with the current number of joins anyway (we just have to perform the addition to produce the compound totals).

Here's some example code, from one of the views in question:

```
COUNT_BIG ( [UVCE]. [ID] ) AS [TotalU] ,
COUNT_BIG ( [SVCE]. [ID] ) AS [TotalS] ,
COUNT_BIG ( [TVCE]. [ID] ) AS [TotalT] ,
COUNT_BIG ( [CVCE]. [ID] ) AS [TotalC] ,
COUNT_BIG ( [WVCE]. [ID] ) AS [TotalW] ,
/* More individual totals, etc. */

COUNT_BIG ( [SCE].  [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [TCE].  [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [CCE].  [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [WCE].  [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [UVCE]. [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [SVCE]. [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [TVCE]. [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [CVCE]. [ID] ) +
COUNT_BIG ( [WVCE]. [ID] ) AS [OverallTotal] ,

CASE WHEN COUNT_BIG ( [SCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [TCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [CCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [WCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [UVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [SVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [TVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [CVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [WVCE]. [ID] ) >= 64 THEN 4E0 ELSE (
          COUNT_BIG ( [SCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [TCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [CCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [WCE].  [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [UVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [SVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [TVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [CVCE]. [ID] ) +
          COUNT_BIG ( [WVCE]. [ID] ) )
          / ( 64 / 4E0 ) END AS [Score]
```

Comment: can you count once and do an outer query on the counts to generate your final result?

Comment: @Tim3880 That's a good point, I suppose I could - good workaround. Honestly, I might just do that - makes the code less ugly as well.

Comment: I always want to get the aggregate results first. Anything beyond that should work on the very short (usually one row) result. it also saves you some typing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server optimizer is pretty good.

However, you are missing an important point when using aggregation functions.  In general, the `group by` clause is way, way more expensive than the aggregation function calls.  That is, moving the data around to define the groups is the expensive part of the query.  (One exception to this is `count(distinct)`.)

That said, doing dozens of function calls can have a noticeable performance impact.  In SQL Server, it is easy enough to use common table expressions (CTEs) or subqueries to define the values at one level and use them at another.  That said, SQL Server may do this for you.  I just think that other parts of the query are likely to be much more important in terms of performance.